# Scala: self-type does not conform to parent selftype with Int

Tags: scala, generics, self-type

I was referring to the generic numeric programming post [here](http://typelevel.org/blog/2013/07/07/generic-numeric-programming.html). However I am getting compilation error with this code:

```
object V1 {
  trait Addable[A] {
    self: A =>
    def +(that: A): A
  }

  def add[A <: Addable[A]](x: A, y: A): A = x + y

  implicit class MyInt(x: Int) extends Addable[Int] {
    y: Int =>
    override def +(y: Int): Int = x + y
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    add(1, 2)
  }
}
```

Errors are as shown below:

```
V1.scala:9: error: `implicit' modifier can be used only for values, variables and methods
  implicit class MyInt(x: Int) extends Addable[Int] {
                 ^
V1.scala:15: error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method add's type parameter bounds [A <: V1.Addable[A]]
    add(1, 2)
    ^
two errors found
```

How can I fix the self type?

**EDIT**: Updated the code and errors.

Essentially, I want to create a generic method that can add two numbers ( Int, Double etc, ).

Comment: don't you need an `override def` in `MyInt` if you want to override `+`? Also, does it work if you explicitly specify the type parameter i.e. `add[MyInt](1,2)`?

Comment: I guess you didn't fully read the article :) It says there that *The main problem with this is that we can't directly use types out of our control, like those that come in the standard library (ie. Int, Long, Double, BigInt, etc).*, which you experienced directly. That's why typeclass approach is described after that.

Comment: I have updated the code and errors. I am getting `class MyInt cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type V1.MyInt with Int`. I don't understand what that means.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you using? Implicit classes were a new feature in Scala 2.10. If you're using 2.9 or older, then `implicit class` will give you an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`self: A =>` means that any class which actually implements this trait has to extend `A`. The error message `class MyInt cannot be instantiated because it does not conform to its self-type V1.MyInt with Int` (from comments) basically says that `MyInt` doesn't extend `Int`. Since no class can extend `Int`, `Addable[Int]` is impossible to implement.

The message `inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method add's type parameter bounds [A <: V1.Addable[A]]` says that `Int` isn't a subtype of `Addable[Int]`.

> How can I fix the self type?

This approach simply won't work with `Int`. The standard approach uses [the type class pattern](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/02/06/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-12-type-classes.html). In particular for

> Essentially, I want to create a generic method that can add two numbers ( Int, Double etc, ).

there is already a type class `Numeric[T]` in the standard library:

```
def add[A](x: A, y: A)(implicit n: Numeric[A]) = n.plus(x, y) // or simply x + y
```

Comment: the type class pattern starts to makes sense to me now